# SEO/Rails - How to add the title tag to every "link_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, link-to

I'm surprised Rails creator didn't think about that, if someone can help, would be great.

How can we do to change this:

```
<%= link_to "My Title", :controller => "products" %>
```

to this automatically:

```
<%= link_to "My Title", :controller => "products", :title => "My Title" #basically a copy of the text %>
```

I think it could help SEO a lot.

Thanks a lot!

Alex

Comment: That wouldn't help SEO at all — it would be completely redundant. It would add ugly tooltips all over the place and repeat lots of information to screen reader users. Use a title attribute when you need to provide additional information that you either can't include in the link text or isn't important enough to do so.

Comment: I'm surprised you want to do this, isn't the link text enough...?

Comment: David's answer make sense but I had the experience before. It's better to repeat the text than to leave the title tag empty. And I don't have time to specify "additional information" to all of my links. Thanks to both of you for the interest.

Comment: No title tag? What's that got to do with title attributes...? What does "I had the experience before" mean? o_O

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Try something like that

```
def link_to_with_autotitle(title, args = {})
  link_to_without_autotitle(title, args.merge(:title => title))
end
alias_method_chain :link_to, :autotitle
```

Haven't tested the code and do not remember the exact link_to spec but I think you get the idea

Comment: Wouldn't args.merge(:title => title) actually overwrite the title in args, in case one was specified? { :title => title }.merge(args) should be right.

Answer (score 15):

**This is the rails 3 way:**

```
<%= link_to object_path, title: "Path Title" %>
```

Further reading: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-to-use-link-title-attribute-correctly/

Answer (score 9):

Your question is valid and I don't know why you are down-voted, but, the creator of rails DID actually think about this. Actually, you can do it in a very simple manner instead of complicating using a custom method:

```
<%= link_to "Link", { :action => "show" }, { :title => "Title" } %>
```

You can in fact add any parameter you like, not just the title.

Hope this helps!